# shell script for looping two variables at a time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am new to  shell script, and i am trying to write a small shell script to perform some action on each server. Below is my script

servers_list=$(curl -s http://localhost:8080//upstream_conf?upstream=backend\&id | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d":")
id_list=$(curl -s http://localhost:8080//upstream_conf?upstream=backend\&id | awk '{print $5}' |cut -f2 -d"=")
servers=10.0.10.1 10.0.10.2
id=0 1

based on the id list i need to perform an action on each server separately.

Note:  server 10.0.10.1 id=0
       server 10.0.10.2 id=1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. What did you try? You do know that [builds can be parameterized](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use standard configuration panel, there is a plugin

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

You can select parameter like boolean (checkbox) or choice (list of string) or simply text field. You will not be able to make "Option A deselected make option B disabled" but anyway this is working pretty well.